# How to delete an "Island" of numbers in a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, math

I'm creating a method that takes a 2D array and scans throughout the array to find "Chunks" of numbers that are completely surrounded by zeros and convert those Chunks (I call them the islands) into zeros.

I'm trying to delete all of the "islands" except for the largest one.

For example, for this 2D array

```
1 2 3 2 2 1 
3 2 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 1 3 2
2 3 2 3 2 2
2 2 3 1 1 2
3 2 1 2 3 2
2 3 1 2 3 2
2 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 2 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

After the method the 2D array should now be:

```
1 2 3 2 2 1 
3 2 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 1 3 2
2 3 2 3 2 2
2 2 3 1 1 2
3 2 1 2 3 2
2 3 1 2 3 2
2 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

the small chunk of `1 2`  is "deleted"

Here is a second example, as the method should also take chunks of numbers that are not part of the "main" chunk as Islands and that are on the edges as well.

The original array would be:

```
1 2 3 2 2 1 
3 2 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 1 3 2
2 3 2 3 2 2
2 2 3 1 1 2
3 2 1 2 3 2
2 3 1 2 3 2
2 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 2 3
0 0 0 0 3 2
```

After the method execution, it should be:

```
1 2 3 2 2 1 
3 2 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 1 3 2
2 3 2 3 2 2
2 2 3 1 1 2
3 2 1 2 3 2
2 3 1 2 3 2
2 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In this case, the island

```
1 2 3 
  3 2
```

is deleted because it is separate from the big chunk and is surrounded by zeros.

The following code is the one I have so far, and it does not work as intended. It's wrong because I believe that it's taking the main chunk as an Island, and what happens is that it converts the entire array into zeros instead of deleting only the small Islands. It includes an example, and you should see what It does when you run it.

```
public class destroyIslands {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] example = { {1, 2, 3, 1, 2},
                            {2, 3, 2, 1, 2},
                            {3, 2, 1, 2, 2},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 0, 0, 2, 1} };
        
        example = deleteIslandBoard(example);
        printGrid(example);
    }
    
    public static int[][] deleteIslandBoard(int[][] array) {
      // Create a boolean array to track which cells have been visited
      boolean[][] visited = new boolean[array.length][array[0].length];
    
      // Iterate 
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            // If the cell is not visited and is part of an island
            if (!visited[i][j] && array[i][j] != 0) {
                // Delete the island by setting all cells to 0
                deleteIsland(array, i, j, visited);
            }
        }
      }
      // Return the modified array
      return array;
    }

    public static void deleteIsland(int[][] array, int i, int j, boolean[][] visited) {
      // Check if the current cell is out of board or if it has already been visited
      if (i < 0 || i >= array.length || j < 0 || j >= array[0].length || visited[i][j]) {
        return;
      }
      // Mark the current cell as visited
      visited[i][j] = true; // If the current cell is part of the island, set it to 0
      if (array[i][j] != 0) {
        array[i][j] = 0;
        // Recursively delete the neighboring cells that are part of the island
        deleteIsland(array, i - 1, j, visited);
        deleteIsland(array, i + 1, j, visited);
        deleteIsland(array, i, j - 1, visited);
        deleteIsland(array, i, j + 1, visited);
      }
    }
    
    public static void printGrid(int[][] grid) {
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea of what should I change?

Comment: So the issue is you are trying to delete all of the islands except for the largest one? Is that a constant or will it be randomized each time?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do. And if you are referring to the numbers on the board as a constant, no. The board will be randomized but that is not gonna be an issue, because if the code does not work with the example provided, it will not work in any board.

Comment: Diagonally adjacent non-zero cells are considered to be connected, or only cells that are adjacent horizontally or vertically can form an island?

Comment: I'm not sure yet, but your task looks like a good candidate for application of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure The idea is that you iterate over all the points in your array, and spread them to the sets. This way you distribute all the points in the array over multiple sets. Then it remains only to find the largest set and remove all the rest.

Comment: Suppose you have an array with 11 rows. The middle row is all `0`, and that is the only row which zeros appear. Which "island" should be removed?

Comment: Only cells that are adjacent horizontally or vertically can form an island. Do not count diagonals. in my program the middle row will never be completely empty.

Comment: What if the largest island doesn't touch a border? That is, what if the largest island is entirely surrounded by zeros? Should it remain, with all smaller islands being removed?

Comment: What if the two or three largest islands are equal in size? Is it arbitrary which should remain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved in linear time **O(n)** by treating the cells of the given Matrix as the Vertexes of an *undirected disjointed* [*Graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)).

The task boils down to exploring all [*Connected components*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) (*islands*) in a Graph, and comparing them with each other.

And for that we would need to implement of the Graph-traversal algorithms. I've chosen the [*Depth first search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm for that purpose.

To keep things simple, a Vertex of a graph would be represented as an array `int[]` of two elements containing coordinates of a cell (*feel free to reimplement it by defining a separate class for a Vertex to make each vertex aware of it neighbors by holding a reference to a collection of Vertices*)

For convenience, I've made several changes to your `DestroyIslands` class:

- Introduced an inner class `Island`, which wraps a list of cells that constitute an Island (*Connected component of the Graph*). This class implements `Comparable` in based on size of the cells to make it easier to find the largest Island. And defines the method `destroy()` to nullify the rest Islands.
- Introduced a `static` array `NEIGHBOURS` of type `int[][]` representing all possible adjacent cells, which should be considered while iterating through the matrix from left to right and from top to bottom.
- Reference to the Matrix is stored in the instance field `grid`, and all methods of `DestroyIslands` are defined as instance methods (*if you want to keep them `static`, fill free to change them as you see fit, it would be easy if you grasp the algorithm itself*).

That's how implementation might look like:

```
public class DestroyIslands {
    public static final int[][] NEIGHBOURS = // adjacent cells
        {{0, 1},   // horizontal -
         {1, 0},   // vertical   |
         {1, 1},   // diagonal   \
         {1, -1}}; // diagonal   /

    private List<Island> islands = new ArrayList<>(); // collection of Islands
    private int[][] grid; // matrix
    
    public DestroyIslands(int[][] grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }
    
    public class Island implements Comparable<Island> {
        private List<int[]> cells = new ArrayList<>();
        
        public void addCell(int[] cell) {
            cells.add(cell);
        }
        
        public void destroy() {
            cells.forEach(cell -> grid[cell[0]][cell[1]] = 0);
        }
        
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Island other) {
            return Integer.compare(cells.size(), other.cells.size());
        }
    }
    
    public void deleteIslandBoard() {
        exploreIslands();
        deleteSmallerIslands();
    }
    
    public void exploreIslands() {
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[grid.length][grid[0].length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
                
                if (!visited[i][j] && grid[i][j] != 0) { // if a New Island was found
                    exploreIsland(new int[]{i, j}, visited); // explore the Island, i.e. index all its cell and mark them as visited
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Depth first search implementation
     */
    public void exploreIsland(int[] cell, boolean[][] visited) {
        Island island = new Island();
        islands.add(island); // updating the list of Islands
        
        Deque<int[]> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        stack.push(cell);
        
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int[] next = stack.poll();
            island.addCell(next);
            
            for (int[] shift : NEIGHBOURS) {
                int row = next[0] + shift[0];
                int col = next[1] + shift[1];
                
                if (isValid(row, col) && !visited[row][col]) { // if cell exist, non-zero and not visited yet
                    stack.push(new int[]{row, col});
                    visited[row][col] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isValid(int row, int col) {
        return row >= 0 && row < grid.length
            && col >= 0 && col < grid[0].length
            && grid[row][col] != 0;
    }
    
    public void deleteSmallerIslands() {
        if (islands.isEmpty()) return; // otherwise Collections.max() would throw NoSuchElementException

        Island largest = Collections.max(islands);
        for (Island next : islands) {
            if (next != largest) next.destroy();
        }
    }
    
    public void printGrid() {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] example = {
            {1, 2, 3, 1, 2},
            {2, 3, 2, 1, 2},
            {3, 2, 1, 2, 2},
            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 2, 1}};
        
        DestroyIslands destroyIslands = new DestroyIslands(example);
        destroyIslands.deleteIslandBoard();
        destroyIslands.printGrid();
    }
```

*Output:*

```
1 2 3 1 2 
2 3 2 1 2 
3 2 1 2 2 
0 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/BoG)

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to get the output? I'm not quite understanding what you are doing here

Comment: @MazaPan616 Sorry, but I have a symmetric Question: can you be more specific what exactly you don't understand? Did you check the links? I can add a brief explanation on how to implement DFS algorithm if found linked article in the Wiki confusing. But you have to tell what's your point of confusion.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm not familiar with this type of code and I'm asking how do you print this output into the console?

Comment: @MazaPan616 I've used your method `printGrid()` as is (*the only change, I removed the `static` modifier, an object of type `DestroyIslands` needs to be created in order to use it, all the code used to produce the output is in the answer*). Are you confused by the usage of instance methods, instead of `static` ones?

Comment: I was confused on why there wasn't anything appearing on my console but it was because I didn't know which packages I needed to import but I figured it out. The code now works. thank you

Comment: @MazaPan616 See the link to online Demo in the very end of the answer. You can run the code on Jdoodle and get the same output (all required imports provided in the demo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250505/discussion-between-mazapan616-and-alexander-ivanchenko).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a flood-fill problem which you've already implemented, so the issue now is how do you determine which chunk to keep and which ones to remove.

My first thought towards implementation would be to create a hashmap containing a starting point (I'd imagine the upper-leftmost coordinate) for each island, along with its size (determine this by modifying your flood-fill algorithm to have a running count while traversing an island). You could then sort the hashmap by the island size and call deleteIsland on every island that isn't the largest.